# codeigniter calling private function on cli

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line

Is there a way to call a codeigniter private function on the commandline?

like:

```
php index.php test _test_function args
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, codeigniter blocks that (comparable to requests via web).

Comment: I tried this:

       `public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) {
   redirect('index');
  }
 }`

But you would still be able to run the script remotely right? Is there any way of preventing that? And would it be safe to do so?

Comment: `is_cli_request()` - if true - will always be a (local) CLI request. So you can check for that and throw an exception if it's not. That done you can ensure that your "private" "public" CLI action will be called from CLI only.

Comment: @hakre You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not call Private function in command line using codeigniter.
Codeigniter dose not allow to do this.

Comment: While it does answer the question, answers usually have some more meat (explain a little why it isn't an option or suggest alternatives, etc.).